# How to share a global variable between python and pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a Dash Python application to execute pytest. I need to implement cancellind tests by clicking on a button in dash. So I need to pass a variable between python (dash) and pytest (fixture).

My approach was to add a boolean variable to the config file that will be storing a test cancelling state. By defautl it is false (tests are not cancelled):

```
is_cancelling = False
```

In the dash callback I change the value on this variable if the cancel tests button is clicked:

```
config.is_cancelling = True
```

And in the file with fixtures I created a fixture that checks this value and should exit pytest if it is true:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def exit_pytest_on_click():
    if config.is_cancelling:
        pytest.exit('Exiting pytest')
```

The problem is that in the fixture the value of config.is_cancelling is always the same - new value is not passed. It is as if python and pytest have their own scope, but I didn't find anything about it.

Is there a way to pass a changed value from python to pytest? Or maybe there are other ways to solve my problem with cancelling tests?

Comment: How are you launching pytest?

Comment: By invoking "pytest.main(test_params)", where test_params is a list of tests and other parameters

Comment: It's not clear from the question where this `config` object comes from. Please update the question with a minimal, self-contained, runnable example that demonstrates the problem.